# Visibility of enumeration types and helpers

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a few base units, which I need to keep separate, but for ease of use I would like to group them into one unit. For now I have problem with enumeration types and helpers, not sure if anything else. Is it possible to make this work?

**BaseUnit**

```
type
  TCustomEnum = (ceValue1, ceValue2, ceValue3);

TCustomEnumHelper = record helper for TCustomEnum
  function AsString: string;
end;
```

**GroupUnit**

```
uses BaseUnit;

TCustomEnum = BaseUnit.TCustomEnum;
```

Usage in other units.

```
uses GroupUnit;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  lValue : TCustomEnum;
begin
  lValue := ceValue1; // doesn't work
  lValue := TCustomEnum.ceValue1; // works 
  lValue.AsString; // doesn't work
end;
```

Comment: Nope, this isn't going to work out.

Comment: It looks like you might be thinking you can inherit an enum type. You cannot. That only works on classes. What you're doing here is defining a brand new type which simply re-uses the existing one. So now you have two enum types, each with the same set of values. They're not inter-changeable as you wish.

Comment: On another note, what does `.AsString` have to do with your question? It seems entirely unrelated. Could it be because the prior line is missing a semicolon?

Comment: @JerryDodge The point was to suggest that I can't see helper methods and I didn't want to write an unnecessarily long example.

Comment: @JerryDodge This isn't a brand new type. It's an alias. There is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your experimentation has yielded exactly what is to be expected.

The only reason your third unit has access to `TCustomEnum` is because `GroupUnit` declared a type alias using the same identifier *but only that identifier*. It's important to note that this is an important way in which the Delphi compilation process differs from C++. Whereas C++ recursively pulls all includes into the compilation scope, Delphi only pulls in the **interface** section of directly included units.

- `lValue := ceValue1;` doesn't work because the `ceValue1` isn't defined in the compilation scope.
- `lValue := TCustomEnum.ceValue1;` works because `TCustomEnum` is pulled in in its entirety. That's to say because `TCustomEnum` **is equal to** `BaseUnit.TCustomEnum`: it means `TCustomEnum.ceValue1` must be valid.

  1. You should note similar with objects and records. You can always reference public members, even if you only pull in the class/record type.
  2. This is different from the previous case because you used `ceValue1` without *any* qualification. And there is no unqualified definition for that identifier in scope.
- `lValue.AsString;` this doesn't work because the helper that makes `AsString` available is not in scope.

---

There are situations where declaring type aliases can be useful. But I must point out the the idea of general purpose grouping unit is deeply flawed.

Yes, it does reduce the number of units you have to **use** in order to pull a *large<sup>1</sup> number* of dependencies. I.e. You think you're saving time by replacing `uses Unit1, Unit2, Unit3, Unit4, Unit5, Unit6;` with the shorter `uses GroupUnit;`.

But the large<sup>1</sup> dependencies means you've also pulled in things you don't need. This leads to:

- A poorly managed architecture where everything indirectly depends on almost everything else. (Otherwise known as a "Big Ball Of Mud" *suggested research*.)
- Unnecessary levels of indirection; meaning if you want to find the definition of something you're using, you `Find declaration...` only to get to the alias, and have to `Find declaration...` again to find what you actually want.

Yes, it seems like more work to list each and every thing you're using. But if you're using that many things that it's frustrating you should ask yourself: *Why is my class so complicated?* and then *What's wrong with my design; how can I improve it?*

---

As a final note, you can alias more than just the enum; provided you do so explicitly.

The following might suffice (but again, use it sparingly). *Not least because it's so much work.*

```
unit GroupUnit;

interface

uses BaseUnit;

type
  TCustomEnum = BaseUnit.TCustomEnum;
  TCustomEnumHelper = BaseUnit.TCustomEnumHelper;
const
  ceValue1 = BaseUnit.ceValue1;
  ceValue2 = BaseUnit.ceValue2;
  ceValue3 = BaseUnit.ceValue3;
```

Comment: You appended a superscript 1 to the term large in your answer. I did now expect a footnote further explaining or sourcing it. Did you just miss that or do you want to indicate something different with it?

Comment: @SebastianProske In this instance I used the "large1" twice to link the 2 instances together; not for a footnote reference.

Comment: That superscript thing is really hard to follow, and counter intuitive to me. I've never seen anthing like that before. Even with your comment I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.